# Errors when posting from AngularJS to Amazon S3

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, amazon-s3

I'm building an app on the MEAN (MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, node.js) stack that requires uploading image files to Amazon S3. I'm doing it in the following way:

First, an http `get` is sent to my API, which specifies the 'policy document' for the interaction and returns it to the AngularJS frontend. That backend code looks like this (with the variables filled in):

```
exports.S3Signing = function(req, res) {
    var bucket = "MY_BUCKET_NAME",
        awsKey = "MY_AWS_KEY",
        secret = "MY_SECRET",
        fileName = req.params.userId,
        expiration = new Date(new Date().getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 5).toISOString();

    var policy = { 
        "expiration": expiration,
        "conditions": [
            {"bucket": bucket},
            {"key": fileName},
            {"acl": 'public-read'},
            ["starts-with", "$Content-Type", ""],
            ["content-length-range", 0, 524288000]
        ]};

    policyBase64 = new Buffer(JSON.stringify(policy), 'utf8').toString('base64');
    signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', secret).update(policyBase64).digest('base64');
    res.json({bucket: bucket, awsKey: awsKey, policy: policyBase64, signature: signature});
};
```

The frontend (AngularJS) code for this process looks like this:

```
$http.get('/api/v1/auth/signS3/' + userId).success(function(data, status) {
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append('key', userId);
                formData.append('AWSAccessKeyId', data.awsKey);
                formData.append('acl', 'public-read');
                formData.append('policy', data.policy);
                formData.append('signature', data.signature);
                formData.append('Content-Type', image.type);
                formData.append('file', image);

                $http({
                    method: 'POST',
                    url: 'http://' + data.bucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com/',
                    headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
                    data: formData
                }).success(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function(err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                });
            }).error(function(err, status) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });
```

However, as it is currently, if I post an image I get the following error:

```
Malformed POST Request The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data.
```

If I change the http POST call to the AngularJS shorthand and remove the "content-type": "multipart/form-data" specification, like such:

```
$http.post('http://' + data.bucket + '.s3.amazonaws.com/', formData).success(function(data) {
                    deferred.resolve(data);
                }).error(function(err) {
                    deferred.reject(err);
                });
```

I get the following error instead:

```
 Precondition Failed At least one of the pre-conditions you specified did not hold Bucket POST must be of the enclosure-type multipart/form-data
```

I have tried any combination of conditions and specifications that I can think of. What am I missing here?

Comment: Possible related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098223/uploading-formdata-from-trigger-io-forge-to-amazon-s3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem was with the format of the "file" I was attempting to upload. I was using [this](https://github.com/Mischi/angularjs-imageupload-directive) AngularJS directive, and the format it returns resized images in isn't as an actual file. I'm still using that same directive, but no longer using the image resizing.

I changed the structure of my upload process to do most of the work on the node.js backend. The AngularJS function looks like this:

```
uploadImage: function(image, userId) {
            var deferred = $q.defer(),
                formData = new FormData();

            formData.append('image', image, image.name);

            $http.post('/api/v1/user/' + userId + '/image', formData, {
                transformRequest: angular.identity,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined }
            }).success(function(data, status) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function(err, status) {
                deferred.reject(err);
            });

            return deferred.promise;
        }
```

And the node.js/express endpoint to post looks like this:

```
exports.uploadImage = function(req, res) {
    postToS3 = function(image, userId) {
        var s3bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: config.aws.bucket}}),
            deferred = Q.defer(),
            getExtension = function(filename) {
                var i = filename.lastIndexOf('.');
                return (i < 0) ? '' : filename.substr(i);
            },
            dataToPost = {
                Bucket: config.aws.bucket,
                Key: 'user_imgs/' + userId + getExtension(image.name),
                ACL: 'public-read',
                ContentType: image.type
            };

        fs.readFile(image.path, function(err, readFile) {
            dataToPost.Body = readFile;

            s3bucket.putObject(dataToPost, function(err, data) {
                if (err) {
                  deferred.reject(err.message);
                } else {
                  deferred.resolve(data);
                }
            });
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    };

    postToS3(req.files.image, req.params.userId).then(function(data) {
        res.json(200, data);
    }, function(err) {
        res.send(500, err);
    })
};
```

This is now using Amazon's [AWS sdk for node.js](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornodejs/).

Answer (score 1):

Should work if you only remove:

```
headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
```

and for image I just sent something like:

```
$("#your_image_id").files[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also faced to the same problem. You need to do convert a `dataURI` to a `Blob` and upload the file returned from this function. It's uploading fine with S3 upload.

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    // convert base64/URLEncoded data component to raw binary data held in a string
    var byteString;
    if (dataURI.split(',')[0].indexOf('base64') >= 0)
        byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    else
        byteString = unescape(dataURI.split(',')[1]);

    // separate out the mime component
    var mimeString = dataURI.split(',')[0].split(':')[1].split(';')[0]

    // write the bytes of the string to a typed array
    var ia = new Uint8Array(byteString.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
        ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
    }

    return new Blob([ia], {type:mimeString});
}
```